# How to let my compiler more stupid (wrong index)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have encounter a horrible situation.
I usually use visual code to edit my code, also compile and execute in it(F5).
But I found vscode is too smart or ignore some warning message for me. And
output the right answer, which also work fine in Ideone. **But in window cmd or dev C++ my code can't output anything, just return a big number.**

And I find some situation will occur the thing I mention above.

The code like this

```
for (i = 0; i < g.size(); i++)
{
    int source;
    int dest;
    int minWeight = 999;

    for (j = 0; i < g[j].size(); j++)
    {
        // no edge, come to next condition
        if (!g[i][j])
            continue;
        if (g[i][j] < minWeight)
        {
            source = i;
            dest = j;
            minWeight = g[i][j];
        }
    }
    if
        updateGroup(index, index[source], index[dest]);
    else
        updateGroup(index, index[source], index[dest]);
}
```

You may found that the second for loops have wrong condition statement, it should change 
`j = 0; i < g[j].size(); j++` to `j = 0; j < g[i].size(); j++`

So I wonder to know

1. Are there any way let my vscode more strict?
2. Why it still can output right answer in vscode and ideone?
3. How to avoid or be easier to found where my code wrong when this kind of **no message error**?

Really hope someone can help me, and appreciate all of your suggestion!!

Comment: The answer is very easy - just **pay really close attention**. `for()` loops can be used in variety of ways and it would be pointless to limit them in such a way that they can only use variables declared in the first part. What if I want to do `for(;check_for_condition();;) { ... }`?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Also, be specific about what you observe and what you expected to observe. Note that there's also a difference between observation and interpretation, the latter is only of secondary importance.

Comment: Turn up your warnings as high as possible. Next time you write a `for` loop inside another `for` loop, try putting it in a new function?

Comment: You are responsible for testing and verifying the code you write, not your IDE.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way for the compiler or computer to read your mind and guess what you meant to write instead of what you really did mean.

Even when this mistake results in a bug, it cannot know that you did not intend to write this, or that you meant to write some other specific thing instead.

Even when this bug results in your program having undefined behaviour, it is not possible to detect many cases of undefined behaviour, and it is not worthwhile for a compiler author to attempt to write code to do this, because it's too hard and not useful enough. Even if they did, the compiler could still not guess what you meant instead.

Remember, loops like this don't *have* to check or increment the same variable that you declared in the preamble; that's just a common pattern (now superseded by the safer ranged-for statement). There's nothing inherently wrong with having a loop that increments `i` but checks `j`.

Ultimately, the solution to this problem is to write *tests* for your code, which is why many organisations have dedicated Quality Assurance teams to search for bugs, and why you should already be *testing* your code before committing it to your project.

Remember to concentrate and pay close attention and read your code, and eventually such typos will become less common in your work. Of course once in a while you will write a bug, and your tests will catch it. Sometimes your tests *won't* catch it, which is when your customers will eventually notice it and raise a complaint. Then, you release a new version that fixes the bug.

This is all totally normal software development practice. That's what makes it fun!

Answer (score 2):

1) Crank up your compiler warnings as high as they will go.

2) Use multiple different compilers (they all warn about different things).

3) Know the details of the language well (a multi year effort) and be really, really careful about the code you write.

4) Write (and regularly run) lots of tests.

5) Use tools like sanitizers, fuzzers, linters, static code analyzers etc. to help catch bugs.

6) Build and run your code on multiple platforms to keep it portable and find bugs exposed by different environments/implementations.

Comment: *Use multiple different compilers*  Don't you think that's a bit much? I think whit a good compiler first step should be enough.

Comment: @HMD No. I *don't* think using multiple compilers is "a bit much". The codebase I work on daily is regularly built using MSVC, Gcc and Clang (in both optimized & debug configurations) and they all find different bugs - especially at first when you initially port your code. It also helps keep your program portable. But it's just one of *many* things one can/should do.

Comment: @HMD: It certainly isn't enough. As I explain in my answer, you cannot and should not rely on the compiler to do your job for you! :)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks for the explanation. The portable part is really necessary indeed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I get what you mean and as a clarification, I didn't mean 1st step is enough and others are useless, I just had some doubts about the second statement.